# how can detect the JOB ? if its working on SYS?

Tags: oracle, plsql

There is a JOB working on the database , its inserting record on a table. I detect the job From the session( on the session its working on SYS). but I cannot find it on the database. I execute the below query on my schema user and the system user , still cannot find it.

```
select * from  dba_jobs_running
```

how can detect the JOB ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
select * from USER_SCHEDULER_JOBS
select * from user_scheduler_job_run_details
```

or

```
SELECT job_name, session_id, running_instance, elapsed_time, cpu_used 
FROM dba_scheduler_running_jobs;
```

Comment: Rahul .. oh thanks I was able to see it , but why the above one didnt worked ? and in the user_scheduler_job_run_details there are 2 million record, does it effect the db performance ?

Comment: @Moudiz:- You are welcome. I dont think it will affect the performance.